# Parsing Data in C

Tags: parsing

I am trying to parse some data using C.

The data is of the form:

```
REMARK 280  100 MM MES PH 6.5, 5 % GLYCEROL                                     
REMARK 290                                                                      
REMARK 290 CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC SYMMETRY                                            
REMARK 290 SYMMETRY OPERATORS FOR SPACE GROUP: P 1 21 1                         
REMARK 290                                                                      
REMARK 290      SYMOP   SYMMETRY                                                
REMARK 290     NNNMMM   OPERATOR                                                
REMARK 290       1555   X,Y,Z                                                   
REMARK 290       2555   -X,Y+1/2,-Z
```

I want to extract the "Symmetry Operator" data: X,Y,Z and -X,Y+1/2,-Z and turn the data into two matrices for each set of symmetry operators of the form:

```
[1 0 0   [0           [-1 0 0        [0
 0 1 0    0    and      0 1 0         1/2
 0 0 1]   0]            0 0 -1]       0]
```

for X,Y,Z, and -X,Y+1/2,-Z respectively.

I have not done much data parsing and would appreciate any help anyone could offer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!